# Substitute sympy symbols in vectors using string arguments instead of symbols

Tags: python, sympy

Is there an alternative way to accomplish this:

```
expr = x**3 + 4*x*y - z
expr.subs([(x, 2), (y, 4), (z, 0)])
40
```

By passing, say, ('x', 2) instead of a sympy symbolic x?

I'm trying to apply something similar to this to sympy vectors.

EDIT:

So I tried using a dict in the subs argument, and it works for this type of expression, but not when the symbols are dynamicsymbols (from the mechanics module).

I have some vector

```
v = x*inertial_frame.x + y*inertial_frame.y
```

And I tried using the dict method, but nothing was substituted.

I also tried to substitute into

```
v.to_matrix(some_inertial_frame)
Matrix([
[x(t)],
[y(t)],
[   0]])
```

Using

```
{'x(t)': 1, {'y(t)': 2}
```

but again, nothing was substituted.

Comment: I do not really get why you want to do that. Now you have to write two additional code chars. Furthermore it is possible that two variables have the same name, but a different scope. For instance an expression with two integrals, each with their own `x` for `dx`.

Comment: If I were to hand off this expression to some different scope then I'd also have to pass the symbolic variables as well, right? Wouldn't it be easier in this case to just make the sub using a string?

Comment: yes but two variables with the same name are not per se the same variables.

Answer (score 2):

There is a custom [`mechanics.msubs` function](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/mechanics/api/expr_manip.html#find-dynamicsymbols) specifically for substituting values into expressions built out of `sympy.physics.mechanics.dynamicsymbols`.

Unlike the [`Basic.subs` method](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/basic.py#L851), `mechanics.msubs` does not attempt to convert strings to `dynamicsymbols`. But you can do it yourself by calling `mechanics.dynamicsymbols`:

```
In [126]: mechanics.dynamicsymbols('x')
Out[128]: x(t)
```

---

For example,

```
import sympy as sym
import sympy.physics.mechanics as mechanics

x, y, z = mechanics.dynamicsymbols('x,y,z')
expr = x**3 + 4*x*y - z
substitutions = [(mechanics.dynamicsymbols(name), val) 
                 for name, val in [('x', 2), ('y', 4), ('z', 0)]]
print(mechanics.msubs(expr, substitutions))
# 40
```

Comment: This works! I was going to go with something like {i.__str__() for i in symbols} but I think this is a much more opaque approach. Thanks.